# "fillna" command in python not returning mean using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, fillna

I am trying to run the fillna command in python. It simply fails to replace the Nan values with anything, and it does not return an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
import numpy as np
url='https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data'
s=requests.get(url).content
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
df.columns=['Scn', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'CLASS']


df.to_csv("wisconsinbreast.csv")

m,n=df.shape
#print(m,n)
df = df.replace('?', np.nan)
#print(df)
#print(df.mean()) 
print(df.fillna(df.mean()))
```

In line 22, Nan is still there. I have done everything that I can find by searching questions here, but this is not even giving me feedback on why it is failing. As I understand it, the df.mean should calculate without the Nan values, but df.mean does not return a value for the column that contains Nan.

Comment: what is your error ? what are your inputs, ouputs, expected outputs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `na_values` in `read_csv`

That `'?'` trips everything up.  When `read_csv` sees it, it assumes the whole column is of dtype `object` and reads it in as strings.  Sure, you could fix this after the fact but I suggest using the `na_values` argument to head this off at the beginning:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')), na_values=['?'])
```

---

#### `pd.to_numeric`

But if you really wanted to fix it after the fact, do this instead of the `replace`

```
df.A7 = pd.to_numeric(df.A7, errors='coerce')
```

In either case, the `fillna` should work as expected afterwards

```
df.fillna(df.mean())

         Scn  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6         A7  A8  A9  A10  CLASS
0    1002945   5   4   4   5   7  10.000000   3   2    1      2
1    1015425   3   1   1   1   2   2.000000   3   1    1      2
2    1016277   6   8   8   1   3   4.000000   3   7    1      2
3    1017023   4   1   1   3   2   1.000000   3   1    1      2
4    1017122   8  10  10   8   7  10.000000   9   7    1      4
5    1018099   1   1   1   1   2  10.000000   3   1    1      2
6    1018561   2   1   2   1   2   1.000000   3   1    1      2
7    1033078   2   1   1   1   2   1.000000   1   1    5      2
8    1033078   4   2   1   1   2   1.000000   2   1    1      2
9    1035283   1   1   1   1   1   1.000000   3   1    1      2
10   1036172   2   1   1   1   2   1.000000   2   1    1      2
11   1041801   5   3   3   3   2   3.000000   4   4    1      4
12   1043999   1   1   1   1   2   3.000000   3   1    1      2
13   1044572   8   7   5  10   7   9.000000   5   5    4      4
14   1047630   7   4   6   4   6   1.000000   4   3    1      4
15   1048672   4   1   1   1   2   1.000000   2   1    1      2
16   1049815   4   1   1   1   2   1.000000   3   1    1      2
17   1050670  10   7   7   6   4  10.000000   4   1    2      4
18   1050718   6   1   1   1   2   1.000000   3   1    1      2
19   1054590   7   3   2  10   5  10.000000   5   4    4      4
20   1054593  10   5   5   3   6   7.000000   7  10    1      4
21   1056784   3   1   1   1   2   1.000000   2   1    1      2
22   1057013   8   4   5   1   2   3.548387   7   3    1      4
23   1059552   1   1   1   1   2   1.000000   3   1    1      2
24   1065726   5   2   3   4   2   7.000000   3   6    1      4
```

Comment: I think that is why I was getting 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str' while trying to solve it for the op :) interesting point, thank you!